# Unable to set iconBase and tickIcon using data attributes using bootstrap-select

Tags: bootstrap-select

I'm trying to set `iconBase` and `tickIcon` using data attributes [as described in the manual](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/), but it doesn't work (the icons don't show up). What am I doing wrong?

```
<link href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>

<select class="selectpicker show-tick" data-iconBase="fa" data-tickIcon="fa-check" multiple>
    ...
</select>
```

Comment: have you tried this with jQuery `$('.show-tick').attr('data-iconBase', 'fa')`

Comment: @Shaybi Haven't tried, I don't want to use JavaScript. But could be interesting to test regardless.

Comment: @Shaybi Works when I set it through Javascript.